# tensorflow: <built-in function AppendInt32ArrayToTensorProto> returned NULL without setting an error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Had various issues getting `tensorflow` onto my system and eventually did with v1.4.1. Trying to run this: https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow

```
SystemError: built-in function AppendInt32ArrayToTensorProto returned NULL without setting an error
```

Searched and couldn't find this specific issue or any patches in newer versions with this same isusue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an **older Tensorflow version**, which is probably **not compatible with your current python version**.

1. check your computer configuration and install a matching Tensorflow version with the help of the following table: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location
2. Install a python version that matches your Tensorflow version (also can be found in the link provided above)
3. Check your python version: $ python3 --version
4. Check your Tensorflow version:$ pip3 list | grep tensorflow
5. If versions are matching as stated in the table above you'd probably get rid of the error

I've encountered a similar problem when I was trying to run the Tensorflow image retraining script: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/raw/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

In my case the problem was caused by **Tensorflow 1.11.0 not being compatible with python 3.7.0.**

Steps that solved the problem for me:

1. Uninstall python 3.7.0.
2. Install python 3.6.0.
3. I run the script again, and now it run properly

Hope it will hellp :)